# Why do we have [rpg] and [first-person-shooter]?

Tags: discussion, tags

How can we be more coherent about tagging?

Comment: Some discussion was held at: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/494/do-we-use-abbreviations-in-genre-names-completed. I've since decided that we could probably shift them to [fps].

Comment: If we do decide something, one of the two synonyms (`rpg` ← `role-playing-game` and `first-person-shooter` ← `fps`) needs to go.

Answer (score 5):

I worry about `[fps]` in particular, since it's commonly overloaded in the gaming community, meaning `[first-person-shooter]` and `[frames-per-second]`.  It's my opinion that we should use always use the long form, and synonym to the short form.

I'm ok with either solution, but for crying out loud, *one way or the other*, and consistent synonyms.

Comment: I actually agree with [Jeff regarding FPS specifically](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-to-tag-use-acronyms-or-not/520#520), because even though we will get questions about frames-per-second, with all due respect "framerate" is a better tag. It is overloaded, but not that significantly, *and* we have a better alternative.

Comment: @Grace I'm willing to accept that.

Comment: Just have `fps` ← `first-person-shooter`, add a synonym and retag the few that are about framerate. Currently the ratio is 3 to 25. I implemented `framerate` ← `frames-per-second`, please check the [synonym proposal](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=framerate&sort=info)

Answer (score 2):

I think we can afford to use TLAs when they're common between experts. `[first-person-shooters]` should become `[fps]`; we can then add a synonym into the system through the tag page, info tab.

Comment: @badp I endorse your request, [fps] instead of [first-person-shooter]

Comment: Because no one will ever confuse that with frames per second...

Comment: Think of the synonym system: what can you do without error, `[fps]` ← `[first-person-shooter]` or `[first-person-shooter]` ← `[fps]`?

Comment: @tzenes: agreed, discussions of FPS in [zone] of [game] are very pertinent to some games, esp mmorpgs where latency kills. FPS for shooters is the more common of the two as its a genre, but frames are common for trouble shooting/advice. i think that FPS (for either meaning) will fail due to its ambivalence. someone could use it to inaccurately refer to Frames / First without realizing it.

Comment: @mfg, if somebody gets it wrong there are many users with the retagging stick who can fix it. We have __26__ questions on first person shooters and all of __3__ questions on framerate, so framerate discussion is quite rare so far. All the fears about FPS also meaning frames per seconds are really overblown.

Comment: @badp consider the following: User comes to the site, wants to know how to increase framerate in Dwarf fortress. Types in the tags [Dwarf Fortress] [FPS].  Both valid tags. Antony comes along (big DF guy on gaming.SE) and knows this is wrong and retags [Dwarf Fortress] [Framerate].  Easy fix.  Now imagine another person come to the site with the same question and searches for [Dwarf Fortress] [FPS].  Gets no results so asks the question again... Or says, this site sucks, and goes away... Or worse goes through and retags every [Framerate] as [FPS].  An [FPS] tag sounds like asking for trouble.

Comment: @tzenes: it's __three__ out of 1,160 questions.

Comment: @badp try to imagine if there were 2,000 [FPS] and 250 [Framerate] (same ratio) and someone goes through and retags them all.  Finding the 250 needles in that Haystack is not something I want to do.  Though, this argument could just as easily be solved by not having an [FPS] tag (making it an unusable tag).  Its not the [Framerate] tag I object to its the [FPS] one.

Comment: @badp i think you have a good point on scale. also, it may not be ideal but regarding re-asking the question, the user would be prompted to check out the other posts about framerate (unless they use only FPS).